# How to receive bytes over a java socket

Tags: java

Suppose a byte string b " \ x00" is sent from some resource over a socket.
If we use socket python and print the output, we get b " \ x00".
If we use java, we get "".
How can one get a byte string in java? And is it even possible.

The code I am using

```
public void start() {
    while (!client.isClosed()) {
        try (DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream())) {
            System.out.println(reader.read(new byte[2048]));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this code relate to your question?

Comment: You're not printing what is read. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read-byte:A-

Comment: Additionally, Can you add logs for both your question and the answer you made for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else faced the same problem. In my case, it's just carelessness

```
public void start() {
        while (!client.isClosed()) {
            try (DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream())) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int lenData = reader.read(buffer);
                for (int i = 0; i < lenData; i++) System.out.println(buffer[i]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```